# find the subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^2$ invariant under $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be the linear operator on $\mathbb{C}^2$ ,the matrix  of which  in the standard order basis is

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & -1 \\
    2       & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

find the  subspaces  of $\mathbb{C}^2$ invariant under $T$

**My attempt** : The characteristic polynomial of $A= |A-Ix|=(x-1)(x-2) + 2=x^2-3x+4$

This is  a parabola opening upwards with vertex $(\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{4})$, so it has no real root

Here  root of $x^2-3x +4$ is $\frac{3 \pm \sqrt 7i}{2}$

Also, we know that  if  $v$ is an eigenvector  of  $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ ,then  its span will be an invariant subspace  of $T$

$\implies$ If $W$ is an invariant subspace  of $\mathbb{C}^2$   then dim $W=1= \dim(\mathbb{C})$

Therefore  the only subspaces  of $\mathbb{C}^2$ invariant under $T$ are $\mathbb{C}$ and the zero susbspace

Is  it true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb C^{2}$ are **isomorphic** to $\mathbb C$ but they are not equal to $\mathbb C$. In fact, $\mathbb C$ is not a subset of $\mathbb C^{2}$. You have to  find the eigen vectors corresponding to the eigen values you have found and the spans of these vectors give you the one dimensional subspaces which are invariant. You should also  observe that $\mathbb C^{2}$ is itself an invariant subspace.

Comment: okay kavi sir .That means all of the invariant subspaces are $\{(0,0)\},\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C^2}$. Am i right ?